# Logstash : Mutate gsub doen't change anything

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

No matter what i change it feels like the gsub is just ignored.

```
"port": 5021,
"@timestamp": "2020-07-25T02:16:03.747Z",
"host": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
"@version": "1",
"message": "000 361.609\r"
```

This is my output, ultimately i want to remove everything after the backlash (backlash included) from the message field. Right now i'm just trying to target the r and even that doesn't work so i need help figuring out what's wrong.

```
filter {
  mutate{ 
    gsub => [
    "message", "[r]", ""]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `"[\\r]"`?

Comment: yes, it also did nothing

Comment: And what about `"[\\s+]"`, i.e. replace any whitespace characters?

Comment: just tried it and it doesn't work either. I tried replacing my zero by another number so:

"message", "[0]", "1"

and this works ! there must be something with the backslash ..

Answer (score 0):

The /r is read directly as a spacing character so a white space and not as the text "/r" so by going with

```
filter {
  mutate{ 
    gsub => [
    "message", "[\s+]", ""]
  }
}
```

the problem is solved !

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!